# Existing Flyway migrations fail validation after upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I just upgraded my Spring Boot application from `2.3.5.RELEASE` to `2.4.2`. Now, when I try to start my application on an existing database, the Flyway migration fails with `Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation`. There's no details or other messages, just this one. Usually Flyway will inform me about checksum mismatches or other issues, but in this case there's nothing.

Did I miss some backwards incompatible change, either in Spring (Boot) or in Flyway? How do I fix my migrations?

Comment: Were you using the default version of Flyway (6.4) with Spring Boot 2.3? Spring Boot 2.4 has upgraded to Flyway 7.1 so if you were previously overriding the Flyway version and using 5.x, you may need to upgrade to Flyway 6.x with Spring Boot 2.3 before upgrading to Spring Boot 2.4 and Flyway 7. This is mentioned in the [release notes for 2.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#flyway).

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I went back to double check. Yes, I was using Flyway 6.4.4 before the upgrade. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: It looks like the new version of Flyway just doesn't report issues beyond "Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation" at all any more. While that doesn't help me figure out why it's failing after the upgrade, it at least explains the unhelpful message.

Comment: And it was fixed in 7.2.0: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#7.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with spring Boot 2.4.2 and Flyway with the same error message "Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation" without any more details.

It happened because I had a gap between my scripts versions numbers.
I had to add `ignoreMissingMigrations(true)` in the flyway configuration to make it work again.

I don't know why this flyway version do not report the missing migration script anymore...

Comment: Setting this option may be just hiding the real issue. The problem is that the version of flyway included in spring boot 2.4.2 has an issue with logging validation errors. Version 7.2.0 of flyway fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Flyway 7.1.0 comes with Spring Boot 2.4. However this version of Flyway does not log the validation exceptions correctly (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes).

I temporarly manage this dependency by myself by adding following code in the maven pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
       <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
       <version>7.2.1</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Good hint to get to the root cause of the issue.